# Can we send a notification to phones enrolled on the Android Management API solution (google)

Tags: google-api, android-notifications, android-management-api, apiclient

I have enrolled a phone via google solutions (Android Management API: https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies). This one is correctly enrolled and all works correctly.

My question is very simple: Can we send an Android notification to this phone just by using google api ?

I have searched a lot on google and it doesn't seem to be implemented. Do you know if this will be implemented soon or never?

If we can't go through google api (Android Management API), what would be the most efficient way to notify a phone?

Thank you,
Sincerely.
Adrien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, AMAPI does not have a feature for sending notifications to the device using the cloud DPC. You will have to implement notifications in a companion app to support the desired functionality.